# "Lock" brakes so that they are always active

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, theft

I have mechanical disc-brakes on my mountain bike. I am wondering whether it is possible to have the brakes activated without me pressing the levers.

Comment: Is this a problem you are having or something you want to achieve - like a parking brake on a car?

Comment: something I want to achieve

Comment: I had a bike with parts of the cable exposed between cable stops along the top tube. Wedging an object between the cable and the frame served me some times to use as "parking brake".

Comment: An alternative is to have an elastic band strong enough to depress the brake lever, or a "velcro" strap. That would serve as a parking brake for almost ANY bike and brake type.

Comment: Tightening a strap around the lever, or sticking a wedge between the lever and lever block, are both common tricks used on recumbent trikes as parking brakes.

Comment: It would help if we had a bit more context around your question. Are you after a simple 'strap around the brake lever' solution, or some electromagnetically operated device with remote application?

Comment: Do you want to have a brake always operating unless you pull the lever? Something like having the lever acting as "brakes releaser" instead of "brakes activation"?

Comment: Would getting someone else to do it for you work?

Comment: @pmatt bicycles.SE is not a typical forum, its a Q&A site, the more information you can provide in the questions, the better answers you will get.  Asking questions while keeping the problem you want to solve secret does not work well with this kind for format.  you may find https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask useful.

Answer (score 7):

I test-rode a trike that had a parking brake lever.  There was an extra button underneath the housing and when you pull the lever, it clicked in and holds brake lever locked down.

To release parking brake,  you squeeze the lever a bit more and the button pops out.

The brake is to help you load your cargo with the trike not rolling away.

https://www.huskybicycles.com/bicycle-brake-lever-wlock-v-type-left-hand.html looks like it.

Comment: I have installed these on bikes that tow trailers,both cargo and kid haulers. It keeps the bike in place while the kids are getting strapped in.

Comment: I've seen these - seems like a good idea, but what happens if you manage to bump it on while riding ?  Definitely not something for an MTB used offroad, but perfect for a shopping bike or tourer.

Comment: @Criggie, you need to pull the brake such that the bike will come to a full stop before you can push that button. Then you relax the brakes a bit and the bike should still be hold at a full stop on the parking brake. Not something you do by accident. (I have parking brakes on two trikes.)

Answer (score 3):

Mechanical disc calipers typically have an external lever which is pulled by the cable to move the pads onto the rotor. You can try using something like a zip tie to pull and fix the lever.

You can also just wind in the barrel adjuster on the cable but you’d need to re-adjust the caliper when you release it.

Comment: Or some tie working on the 'hook and loop' principle, usually called a V....o tie, a large O-ring or just a piece of string.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble parking my bike against poles and walls where the front wheel flops over and the whole bike crashes into the ground.  I've used the parking brake levers mentioned here that have a dropdown pin that holds the brake tight.  However,  unless your brake lines are correctly calibrated you are either holding a very tight stretch (bad for the cables) or they have very little hold.

The best method I've found is to use a section from an old inner tube, tied around the handlebars, to always give the right amount of pressure and in short time.

1. Tie a piece of inner tube to your handlebar near where the brake lever ends in a double knot (or whatever your favorite knot is).  Keeping the full round of the tube is not entirely necessary, it could be a strip.
2. Add a loop to the longer free and and pull it most of the way through the gap between the knot and the handlebar.
3. Tension the knot so that it holds the loop with friction.
   [image: Knot when parking brake is not engaged]
4. When parking, pull the loop over the brake lever.
5. Pull the free end tight until brakes are engaged.
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

for the elastic band option, to get something made specific

google: Bike Brake – The Parking Break for your Bicycle

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Please don't post suggestions for how to find an answer, if you know where the answer is, post it directly.  You might want to read [answer].